# NameError: uninitialized constant TurboDevAssets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, diaspora

I'm learning rails. I downloaded the code from https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora but it can't run. It's the error codes:

```
/home/a1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/web/diaspora/config/environments/development.rb:42:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant TurboDevAssets (NameError)
    from /home/a1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/a1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `configure'
    from /home/a1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:182:in `configure'
    from /home/a1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/web/diaspora/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

The *config/environments/development.rb* is:

```
Diaspora::Application.configure do
    [...]
    # Speed up asset serving
    config.middleware.insert 0, TurboDevAssets
 end
```

How to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Open your Gemfile and make sure this line is in there:

```
  gem "turbo_dev_assets", "0.0.2"
```

If it is but you're getting that error move that line outside a conditional or to one of the conditional sections where you know it will get picked up when you run the command:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bin/bundle install --deployment --with "development test postgresql"
```

Then verify in the output of that command that you see this line:

```
Installing turbo_dev_assets 0.0.2
```

This should resolve the error:

```
Name error ,uninitialized constant TurboDevAssets (NameError)
```

Comment: The `--jobs $(nproc)` there is a bit misleading. It is not necessary for the task and, also, `nproc` only exists in Linux systems

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I have edited the answer to remove the --jobs $(nproc), a result of copy/paste on Ubuntu that I overlooked. I did not account for "portability". Thanks!

Comment: The command `RAILS_ENV=development bin/bundle install --deployment --with development --with test --with postgresql` doesn't work as expected with modern bundler, you actually have to run `RAILS_ENV=development bin/bundle install --deployment --with development test postgresql`. I tried to edit the post twice, but my edit was rejected with no explanation

Comment: @senya your solution works for modern bundler but is not portable to older bundler, the behavior has change and as such should be place in a comment not a global edit to the entire solution! Cheers. -K

Comment: @Kaleb I asked on the Bundler official Slack channel and they told me that multiple `--with` never was officially supported behavior. [Screenshot](https://framapic.org/nAOfJrEJjtEz/AGrzZCU1xCkl.png).

Answer (score 0):

You must run bundle install.

TurboDevAssets is a gem within the gemfile:

```
  gem "turbo_dev_assets", "0.0.2"
```

Bundle install will setup it up.

Comment: What he means here is to add that line to the "Gemfile". It should already be in the "development" section but if it is not loading try moving it to a section you know will run it or just move it outside all conditions so it is forced to load.

Then re-run the command: RAILS_ENV=development bin/bundle install --jobs $(nproc) --deployment --with development --with test --with postgresql